# Unable to retrieve MySQL ID

Tags: php, mysql

why am I unable to get the ID this way:

```
 . $row['ID'] .
```

or this way

```
 . $row['events.ID'] .
```

When my code looks like this? Thank you so much!

Edit: I get no errors, but the field is blank.

```
$query =    
"SELECT
    events.ID,
    events.EVENT_NAME,
    events.start_datetime,
    events.end_datetime,
    events.VENUE_LOCATION,
    events.PARTY_TYPE,
    events.SMALL_POSTER_URL,
    events.ENTRANCE_PRICE, 
    venues.VENUE_NAME,
    venues.BEER_PRICE,
    venues.WINE_PRICE,
    venues.SPIRITS_PRICE, 
    party_types.PARTYTYPE,
    GROUP_CONCAT(music_styles.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) AS MUSIC_STYLE_NAME
FROM events
INNER JOIN venues 
    ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID
INNER JOIN party_types
    ON events.PARTY_TYPE = party_types.ID
INNER JOIN events_music_styles
    ON events.ID = events_music_styles.event_id
INNER JOIN music_styles
    ON events_music_styles.music_style_id = music_styles.id
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
GROUP BY events.ID
";



$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
```

Comment: Do a print_r($row) inside the loop and see what is actually in the variable.

Comment: Are you calling `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`? What does `var_dump($row)` tell you?

Comment: Hey Corbin, doing a `print_r ($row)` shows everything including the ID nicely.

Comment: Sorry  The Guy Of Doom, I probably misunderstood your question. Sorry I'm pretty inexperienced :(

Comment: SHOW THE CODE WHERE YOU ACTUALLY ADDRESSING THIS VARIABLE. Otherwise the whole question makes not a slightest sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mysql_fetch_row($result)` will return rows as an enumerated array, you need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` to get an associative array

Comment: @pufAmuf what's the matter? you are already using right syntax and have your data. why you are accepting wrong answer? It is not good.

Comment: Hey Your Common Sense, it worked for me which is why I accepted it.

Comment: @pufAmuf it is not this solution worked for you. HERE are your own words: `doing a print_r ($row) shows everything including the ID nicely.` - so, you had your data already without this answer. Can't you see it? Where is your LOGIC?

Comment: This is just a random answer out of nowhere, not related to the question. -1

Comment: @Your Common Sense, his initial question was lacking some actual code, but you could have guessed the answer and his code judging from his comments. The "shows everything including the ID nicely" meant it was showing him the value of the ID, not the "ID" keyword

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you are just missing the `mysql_fetch_assoc(..)`

do this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

and then you can use `$row["ID"]`

If this doesn't work, try

```
SELECT
 events.ID as id,
 events.EVENT_NAME,
 ...
```

then you can access it via `$row["id"]`

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks Stefan! The first example didn't work completely because it removed some results from my query for some reason. Shocker's theory worked, but I haven't tried the second idea you mentioned. Nonetheless, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Actually, I upvoted all answers. Somebody else must have downvoted you.

Comment: This is just a random answer out of nowhere, not related to the question. -1